# A-frame Lit shadow dom interferes with a-scene

Tags: aframe

I am developing an A-Frame application bootstrapped with `npm init @open-wc`. It uses Lit 2.0.2.

There seems to be some conflict between the enclosing a-scene and the shadow root when using Lit.

If I put the a-scene in the index.html file, the VR controls show up, but something is messed up with the controls, I can't "touch" anything (wasd, mouse look, etc). If I put the a-scene in the Lit element, then the VR controls don't show up.

If I remove the a-scene in the Lit component (leaving it in the html file),  I get this kind of message: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'systems')

With a-scene in the html (and the component), where the VR controls show up but I can't 'touch' anything, the DOM looks like this: body > a-scene > hai-scene > [shadow-root] > hai-scene children

[image: with a-scene in index.html]

With a-scene removed from index.html, the DOM is this: body > hai-scene - [shadow-root] > a-scene > hai-scene children

[image: a-scene only in hai-scene]

Note there is some randomness in the DOM since I was experimenting, but that doesn't seem to affect the result, it seems to be all about the intermediate [shadow-root].

I am kind of a newbie with Lit, shadow DOM, and a-frame, and there is some deep-end stuff here. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a known bug, or is there something I can add?